# Display posts using post ID's in an array

Tags: php, functions, array

I currently have an array of post ID's stored as **$recenty_viewed** that looks like this:

Array ( [0] => 3164 [1] => 3165 [2] => 3168 [3] => 3176 )

I'd like to display each post thumbnail and title using the ID's above, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the data from each post. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get post thumbnail by id =  get_the_post_thumbnail($id);

Get the title by id = get_the_title($id);